# Razor function to query database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, razor

I really like the convenience of this Razor function, where it queries the ASP.NET database to see if the current user is in role "Standard", in this example.

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Standard"))
{
    // Do something...
}
```

I want to find a way to create/use a similar function where it looks in an "organization" database table to find out which organization the user belongs to.

I can't seem to find an elegant solution.

Comment: You can write any c# code you want, including functions, inside a razor page. If you _really_ want to do business logic inside your View, just write it there, but I'd advise that you write business logic in a controller or DI services.

Comment: As @gunr2171 mentioned, the view should not contain business or database logic. All the data you need in the view should be sent from the controller.

Comment: `User.IsInRole` doesn't access your database. It accesses the user principal attached to the HttpContext. The database access probably happened earlier, during authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really put business logic inside a view.

The solution depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you need to check what roles the current user is in, I would **add a property to the ViewModel**, called `UserRoles` that contains all the roles the current user is in.

Pseudocode for the ViewModel:

```
public class SomethingViewModel
{
     public IReadOnlyCollection<string> UserRoles { get; set; } // could be ICollection, IList, etc. depending on your coding style

     // Other properties
}
```

In your Controller:

```
// this implementation is for Asp.Net Identity, use whatever implementation you need.
private IEnumerable<string> UserRoles 
    => ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims
            .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
            .Select(c => c.Value)


public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
     // do some processing
     var viewModel = new SomethingViewModel()
     {
         UserRoles = UserRoles.ToList()
     }
     return View(viewModel);
}
```

And then you use this property in the View:

```
@if (Model.UserRoles.Contains("Standard")) {/* do something*/}
```

This way the **business logic is decoupled from your view** so for example if you change the way you store the roles, you can just simply swap the property above without having to worry about what Views the roles are used in.

Of course you may want to potentially cache UserRoles, etc., this code was just a demonstration of the main idea.

Comment: I'd recommend using a strongly-typed model instead of passing an anonymous object to the view, it would make things easier.

Comment: Totally agreed, see my last paragraph

Comment: yes I saw it, my comment was more a way of suggesting you to edit your answer and adding the view model ;-)

Comment: You guys don't let me be lazy..:P I'll edit in a moment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I ended up calling RenderAction() from the view and inside the controller, I returned a PartialView() depending on the database results. This allowed me to return the necessary HTML depending on the results from the Organization table in the database.